# What happens to my files if I scp-ed to non existing directory

Tags: directory, scp, gzip

Here's what I did:

- copied some files from server to my local computer

  scp root@remotemachine:/var/log/nginx/* /home/me/logs
- deleted the files on the server

The next moment I realized, that I forgot to create the target directory on the local machine (/home/me/logs). Now instead of copied files inside 'logs' I see a file called 'logs' that looks like gzip archive, but file-roller doesn't recognize it as a valid gzip archive.

Comment: `scp` should warn you about any non-existent directory on the destination..didn't you get any such warning ?

Comment: @heemayl I didn't get any warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `scp` will copy each source file to `/home/me/logs`, overwriting `/home/me/logs` with the contents of each new file.

The result is that `/home/me/logs` will be a copy of the last source file in the list. All the other source files are lost.

Oops! Regular `cp` warns and aborts in this case, at least!

Comment: damn.. i really messed this up :)